# HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action and result input : adding result type input prevents submit

Tags: jsp, file-upload, struts2, struts, actionresult

I have a form in which I have :

**JSP:**

```
<form name="xyz" action="upload">
    <input type="file" name="upload"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<action name="upload" class="uploadClass" method="saveExcel">
    <result name="success">page1.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

For this it gives an error :

```
HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action and result input
```

And if I modify `struts.xml` as :

```
<action name="upload" class="uploadClass" method="saveExcel">
    <result name="success">page1.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">page1.jsp</result>
</action>
```

When I try to submit the form the page reloads.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Whatever other problems there may be you need to have the form as a multipart.

Comment: show your `saveExcel()` code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to use encoding `multipart/form-data` for your form if you are file uploading.

```
<form name="xyz" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="upload"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Struts were not accept your file sent by the request if it's not encoded to `multipart/form-data` and file upload errors occurred. You can check what errors are using `s:actionerror` or `s:fielderror` tags in JSP. Default messages are configured using [File Upload Error Messages](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/file-upload.html#error-messages).

Note, if your action has errors and you have default interceptor stack invoked the [`workflow` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/default-workflow-interceptor.html) will return `INPUT` result. It gives you *refresh* effect.

Comment: "refresh" effect.. wonder why I never thought of that word before :D

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that an result named input has not been defined for your action. The result input is a default result returned by Struts when there is a problem with validating the parameters passed to an action.

So if there is a problem in validation , struts-2 framework looks for your mapping for "input" in struts.xml.If you don't have it defined in your struts.xml .It throws that error that can't find.If you have defined it ,it will redirect you to mapped jsp page.So when you submit it 2nd time when you have defined result type input ,It sends you to same page as you have define page1.jsp for it.So your page is reloaded as you were send to same page.